# Rotate a triangle in the cente of itself

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to rotate a triangle in the center of itself.
I have this script:

```js
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var angle = 30;
  setInterval(rotate, 50);
  function rotate() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(150, 150); // x, y
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180)
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    var path=new Path2D();
    path.moveTo(-50+50,-25);
    path.lineTo(-50,-50-25);
    path.lineTo(-50-50,-25);
    ctx.fill(path);
    ctx.restore();
    angle++;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1800" height="700"></canvas>
```

It rotates it, but not in the center. I want it to look like this:

```js
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  setInterval(rotate, 50);
  var angle = 30;
  function rotate() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(50, 50);
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180)

    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(-25, -25, 50, 50);
    ctx.restore();
    angle++;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1800" height="700"></canvas>
```

I think, I just have to get the width and hight of the triangle and devive it by 2, but I don't know, how to do that.
Thx for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create the Path once

You are using a Path2D object which is reusable.

If you create the triangle already centered on its origin (or any path for that matter) it is then trivial to rotate it.

Reusing the path object is also a lot quicker if you have a lot to render.

The function to creates a path from a set of points. It automatically centers the path to its own origin (defined by the mean of its points)

```
const point = (x, y) => ({x, y});
function createPath(...points) {
    var cx = 0; cy = 0;
    for (const p of points) {
        cx += p.x;
        cy += p.y;
    }
    cx /= points.length;
    cy /= points.length;

    const path = new Path2d;
    for (const p of points) { path.lineTo(p.x - cx, p.y - cy); }
    path.closePath();
    return path;
}
```

To create the triangle

```
const triangle = createPath(point(0,-25), point(-50,-75), point(-100,-25));
```

Then you can render it rotated about its own origin with

```
function drawPath(path, x, y, angle) {
     ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
     ctx.rotate(angle);
     ctx.stroke(path);
}
```

### Example

Shows how to create various shapes centered on their means. Each shape is a path created once and then rendered as needed.

```js
const point = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const triangle = createPath(point(0,-25), point(-50,-75), point(-100,-25));
const rectangle = createPath(point(0,-25), point(-50,-25), point(-50,-125), point(0,-125));
const thing = createPath(point(0,-12), point(-25,-12), point(-25,-62), point(0,-62), point(22,-35));

function drawPath(path, x, y, angle) {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.stroke(path);
}

function drawPath_V2(path, x, y, scale, angle, strokeStyle, fillStyle) {
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    fillStyle && (ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle, ctx.fill(path));
    strokeStyle && (ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle, ctx.stroke(path));
}


function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    const scale = Math.sin(time / 500) * 0.2 + 1.0;
    const scale2 = Math.cos(time / 1000) * 0.4 + 1.0;

    drawPath(triangle, 75, 74, time / 1000 * Math.PI); //360 every 2 second

    // scale path
    drawPath_V2(rectangle, 125, 125, scale, time / 2000 * Math.PI, "black"); //360 every 4 second

    // fill scale path
    drawPath_V2(thing, 125, 100, scale2, time / 3000 * Math.PI, "", "black"); 
    
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const can = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {width: 200, height: 200});
document.body.appendChild(can);
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");

function createPath(...points) {
    var cx = 0; cy = 0;
    for (const p of points) {
        cx += p.x;
        cy += p.y;
    }
    cx /= points.length;
    cy /= points.length;

    const path = new Path2D;
    for (const p of points) {
        path.lineTo(p.x - cx , p.y - cy);
    }
    path.closePath();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Thx. Is there a way to fill it black now? And what do I have to do, to change the size of it?

Comment: @AdolfWeii I have updated the code with a new function `drawPath_V2` that has 3 extra arguments. the 3rd argument is scale 1 is same size, <1 is smaller > 1 is larger. Last two arguments are the stroke and fill style.Pass the style to fill and or stroke. Pass undefined (or falsey value) to not stroke or fill (see answer's snippet)

Comment: @Blindmarn67 Your code works really well, thank you a lot! The only problem I am facing right now is that I'd like to pause and reset the rotation. I think the time stamp is great to make sure the rotation speed is the same on every device, but I could not find out how to change or reset the time stamp.

Comment: @AdolfWeii You need to keep track of animation start time (set at first frame `startTime = time`). The animation time is then `currentTime = time - startTime`. To stop the animation you set the start time to `startTime = time - (time - startTime)` each frame that you want the animation to pause,

Comment: @Blindmarn67 Thank you for your answer! I got the **reset** to work using `startTime = time`. I could not get your solution for **pausing** to work. I think if you simplify the code it is `startTime = startTime` and it makes sense, because when you have the timestamp and you subtract the time since startTime (`(time - startTime)`), that is your startTime again. So instead, **I use** `startTime += (time - storedTime);` in the loop. `storedTime` is the timestamp of the last call of the loop, so it just adds the time, that passed since pause was activated, to the start time.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of your shape.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var angle = 30;
var points = [
  {x:0, y:-25},
  {x:-50, y:-75},
  {x:-100, y:-25}
];
// first sum it all
var sums = points.reduce( (sum, point) => {
  sum.x += point.x;
  sum.y += point.y;
  return sum;
}, {x:0, y:0});
// we want the mean
var centroid = {
  x: sums.x / points.length,
  y: sums.y / points.length
};

rotate();
function rotate() {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // general position in canvas
  ctx.translate(100, 100);
  // move to centroid of our triangle
  ctx.translate(centroid.x, centroid.y); // x, y
  // rotate
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180)
  // go back to our initial position
  ctx.translate(-centroid.x, -centroid.y); // x, y

  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  var path=new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  path.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
  path.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
  ctx.fill(path);

  // demo only
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(centroid.x, centroid.y, 50, 0, Math.PI*2)
  ctx.stroke();
  
  angle++;
  requestAnimationFrame( rotate );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1800" height="700"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, you may probably want to check this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390046/8620333 .. we are actually only 2 CSS guys *fighting*. We probably need more opinions.

Comment: Hi. I read that post, and I must admit I'm not comfortable taking part of it in the lights of what happens on the network... and because I'm an easy closer that has been proved wrong in my judgements once or twice. But yes, I would have done exactly the same as you did, I also think it's a dupe, IMM the arguments made by Nick don't hold here; but I'm afraid it's not worth the effort, too much is at play on the table. You might want to ping BoltClock, which is more used to the community handling than I am. Sorry.

Comment: no problem, I understand. At least you agree that it's a duplicate from you expertise perspective which is what I need to hear. Unfortunately Nick is getting a lot of upvotes and I may fail into the position of the *bad closure*. We already pinged Bolt and we are waiting ... (PS: you can cast your vote since you don't have the CSS gold and it will count as one towards the 5 needed, no one will blame you doing so)